# Why is the ubuntu always updating and occupied the Harddisk memeory after installing the 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I don't know why the ubuntu 14.04 LTS always update and occupied hard disk memory  every week recently for around tens or hundreds Mega bytes memories. 
   It will increase it size to occupy the HD space and make it almost can't update any more.
   So is there something wrong?

Comment: error message, gparted screen shot, what are you trying to update?

Answer (score 1):

14.04 was released almost 2 years ago. http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu

Since the LTS versions are supported for 5 years, there are going to be lots of updates.  What you are going through is normal.  If hard drive space is that big of an issue, you could reinstall on a larger partition or switch to a newer version.

Comment: Updates don't normally consume all that much additional disk space, except temporarily as the files are downloaded. Once installed, the new packages *replace* old ones that are usually almost as big as the new ones. There are some exceptions, though. Most importantly, there's [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1357093) that affects kernels. (A fix has been committed, but not yet released.) This bug is most important on systems with separate `/boot` partitions.